# How can I replace Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in proxy response with nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

I am using a simple nginx instance to proxy REST calls to another server. The purpose of my proxy is to allow the use of cookies for authentication. I have it working, except for one problem. The server providing the REST service is sending the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`. That header is too permissive for cookie based authentication. I need to replace that header with one that is more restrictive.

Here is a subset of my nginx config:

```
map $http_origin $cors_header {
    default "";
    "~^https?://[^/]+\.mydomain\.com(:[0-9]+)?$" $http_origin;
}

server {    
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://myrestserver.com/api;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors_header;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I end up with two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers present in my response. How can I replace the header that comes back from the REST server so that only my version of the header is present in the final response?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to change the response on the REST server side, but, assuming you don't have control of the REST server, there is a module for Nginx that can modify headers called ngx_headers_more: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module

You'll have to install the module (this will likely involve building nginx from source and adding the module in ./configure, as described in the github readme). For your specific problem, once you install it you can add this directive in any block

```
more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $cors_header"
```

Comment: You may or may not need to use "more_clear_headers" before "more_set_headers". I do, but not sure if it was me being cautious or actually needing to. Building nginx is pretty easy, I have a guide coming out that includes that soon.

Comment: You don't actually! As the docs say, more_set_headers "Replaces (if any) or adds (if not any) the specified output headers..." but I doubt the cautious approach adds significant overhead.

Comment: Good to know :) You're right, I clear some headers like "Server" (for security) and "Pragma" (because it's old) and just set the headers I care about.

Comment: This did work without needing to use more_clear_headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

this works without extra nginx modules

```
proxy_hide_header 'access-control-allow-origin';
add_header 'access-control-allow-origin' '*';
```

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens You hide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that you get back from the server you proxy to with `proxy_hide_header` and then you add your own custom header with `add_header`. This answer is the only way to "replace" a header in Nginx as far as I know. Upvote from me!

Comment: I got `proxy_hide_header directive is not allowed here` so it is not working for me without further explanations...

Comment: @m13r you cannot put proxy_hide_header inside an if block.

Answer (score 0):

Folllow ***exe-dealer*** answer and if you are using php to set header you can make:

```
# always set a new header
add_header  access-control-allow-origin "*" always;

# remove header that came from php
fastcgi_hide_header access-control-allow-origin;
```